# Fancybox image disappear

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox, fancybox-2

The image keeps on disappearing after the image is clicked.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="picture-container">
        <div class="picture-box">
            <a href="gallery/img1.JPG" class="fancybox" rel="group"><img src="gallery/small-images/img1.JPG"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="picture-box">
            <a href="gallery/img2.JPG" class="fancybox" rel="group"><img src="gallery/small-images/img2.JPG"></a>
         </div>
     </section>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

JavaScript

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        context = $('#picture-container');
        $("a.fancybox", context).fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Solved it myself :
'
#picture-container img {

        display: block !important;

}'

After each click the image would go to display: none. That's the solution.

Comment: It would have been easier just binding fancybox without any context like `$("a.fancybox").fancybox();` ... see your code working http://jsfiddle.net/rUBrt/ .... why over-complicating things?

Comment: Would that be easier to find the class i.e. by using contexts?

Answer (score 0):

How it was answered (2014), in this link here in Stack:

[Thumbnails disappears after click on them, FancyBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909412/thumbnails-disappears-after-click-on-them-fancybox)

Set the `href` like the `src` in `img`:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="image_source" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""><img src="image_source" alt="" /></a>
```