# Thumbnails disappears after click on them, FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I created FancyBox gallery.
But now when I click on thumbnails it shows up image galery as planned.
But in background I can see that all thumbnails are disappearing one by one. After F5 or page reload all thumbnails are back.

**My code:**

```
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""> <%=  image_tag('s_1.jpg') %></a>
    <a class="fancybox"  data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""><%= image_tag('s_2.jpg') %></a>
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""><%= image_tag('s_3.jpg') %></a>
   <a class="fancybox"  data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""> <%= image_tag('s_4.jpg') %></a>
   <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery"  title=""> <%= image_tag('s_5.jpg') %></a>
```

In **application**.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Example you can see [here](http://darbs.ecotechno.lv/en/services)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to have an image source defined in the `<a>`-tag. Even if you don´t have different size images for thumbnail and gallery view you still need to define it twice, like so:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="image_source" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""><img src="image_source" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: +1:Otherwise fancybox will treat the thumbnail as inline content and will place it back hidden after close